# Using QuickBlox in a Android library project

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm testing QuickBlox Android API. 
All the samples works fine at my environment.
So I try to create a Android library project to separate everything about Chat, because I will use this functionality in other projects so I want to reuse some code.

But It didn't work. 
When I use my library(with QuickBlox jar there) in a Android project I can't create a session.

Below, you will see my code to create a Session:

```
    QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(getAppId(), getAuthKey(), getAuthSecret());
    QBAuth.createSession(new AuthenticationCallback(this));
```

It never calls the method
public void onComplete(Result result) 
from the QBCallback I passed.

I got this log below on the logcat

=== REQUEST ==== 76e23110-eda0-470d-bc7f-65f93d83c1ba ===
REQUEST
POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
HEADERS
QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
QB-SDK=Android 1.2.3
 PARAMETERS
application_id= [MY APP ID NUMBER]
 auth_key= [MY APP AUTH KEY]
nonce=-1363221055
 timestamp=1407524693
signature=0e763d80ac3ebb60f266f3faef59c21994d535b8
INLINE
POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json?application_id=MY_APP_ID&auth_key=MY_AUTH&nonce=-1363221055&timestamp=1407524693&signature=0e763d80ac3ebb60f266f3faef59c21994d535b8

Everything works fine if use this code directly in my project without using a Android project library.

So What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where you call createSession? Is it some class-wrapper or what?

Comment: My library project has a Activity SplashScreen with the method createSession. This method will be called at the onCreate method. My first Activity in my implementation project will inherit this SplashScreen passing the Authorization data (APP ID, AUTH KEY, AUTH SECRET).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, nothing logged, I finally just guessed that I hadn't given permission to the app to connect to the internet.  Make sure to add internet access in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Fixed my issue right up!  Wish that was logged someplace to make it more obvious, wasted a few hours on this!!  Silent fails suck!!